# Rails 4 scope through belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, rails-activerecord, acts-as-shopping-cart

I am trying to scope through an array of child records based on a value in one of the parent columns. I am trying to find all the ShoppingCartItems  that belong to a Product with a category "Bundle."

I am trying to use acts_as_shopping_cart_gem

My Models.

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shopping_carts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

ShoppingCart.rb

```
class ShoppingCart < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_shopping_cart_using :shopping_cart_item
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :shopping_cart_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :shopping_cart_items
end
```

Product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shopping_cart_items,  dependent: :destroy
end
```

ShoppingCartItem.rb

```
class ShoppingCartItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product,  dependent: :destroy

  scope :bundles,  ->  { 
    joins(:product).where('products.category = ?', 'Bundles') unless category.blank?
  }

end
```

I am getting this error:

```
> undefined local variable or method `category' for
> #<Class:0x007fc0f40310d0>
```

Comment: What are you getting now? An error or no returned records or the wrong records?

Comment: error: undefined local variable or method `category' for #<Class:0x007fc0f40310d0>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually straight forward - there is nowhere you defined the `category` variable.

This is how I would do that (generalized scope):

```
scope :by_category, lambda { |category|
  joins(:product).where(products: { category: category })
}
```

Note, there is no `unless` statement - if the category is not passed to scope, it will raise the ArgumentError.

Then use the scope for any category:

```
ShoppingCartItem.by_category('Bundles')
```

To prevent the blank category to be passed into scope, just make sure you pass the right string. You can create a dropdown of categories:

```
Product.pluck(:category)
```

or something similar, if it is a part of user interface.

Comment: Yes,  this is SO BEAUTIFUL.  I will be scoping with different categories, so this is by far the best way to handle this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The category field on your scope regards the ShoppingCartItem? If so, try `self.category.blank?`. If not, just remove the unless statement.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add `Category` model and add this relation:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shopping_cart_items,  dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :category
end
```